# Seeking 1841/1851 Census Records for Ryle Holme, perhaps in Manchester, England?

Tags: census-records, united-kingdom, japan, 1840s, 1850s

I am interested in Ryle Holme who is the uncle of C.Z. Ede, a candidate for my great-grandfather, who I have asked about in a number of previous questions.

He was greatly concerned with the Meiji Restoration of Japan so I would like to learn more about him.

There seemed to be a Ryle Holme in the Jardine Matheson company who came to Japan in 1860.

Ryle Holme was born in 1839 at Manchester.

His census records have not been found.

His parents were Matilda Wilhelmina Zohrab and Thomas Holme.

Where might I locate a Census Record for him, perhaps in the England Census of either 1841 or 1851?

Comment: I can give you more information on Thomas who died about 1846 and also James and Constantine. I am interested in the Ede connection as Sydney Cuthbert Ede ended up in Australia with constantine. I am also trying to determine when Thomas and Matilda married.

Comment: @RobChristie to get that Infomation to Akira and possibly to find an answer to your own question you could ask it as a new question using the information as background to it.

Answer (score 4):

His name has been indexed as Kyle rather than Ryle by Ancestry.com in the 1841 Census, aged 2, at Broughton, Lancashire with his parents Thomas (40) and Matilda (30) and siblings James (12), Constantine (10) and Edward (5).  Thomas' occupation is a little hard to read but it appears to be Agent, and Matilda was born in foreign parts.

> Class: HO107; Piece: 579; Book: 7; Civil Parish: Broughton; County:
>   Lancashire; Enumeration District: 6; Folio: 32; Page: 18; Line: 23;
>   GSU roll: 438731

His parents are not recorded together in the 1851 Census.

- Matilda, aged 37, born in Constantinople, Turkey, is living at Cheetham, Lancashire, with two of Ryle's siblings Constantine (20) and Edward Y (14), and two other adults Eliza Hunter (27) and Ann Roberts(29).

> Class: HO107; Piece: 2232; Folio: 114; Page: 40

- I have not found Thomas (who should be aged about 50), James (who should be aged about 22) and Ryle (who should be aged about 12).

Comment: I think that he is a person of consequence in case of the Meiji Restoration of Japan. The researcher of the Hoover Institute agrees to this opinion, too. Because he is an uncle of C.Z.Ede, I want to question him.